# Замена данных в ячейках float

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++builder, visual-studio-2015, float

Имеется некоторое число float. Необходимо написать программу, которая заменяет в представлении этого числа последний байт на значение "0xAA" и, после изменения, выводит новое число(полученное в результате изменения). Буду благодарен за вашу помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что нет даже попытки подумать самостоятельно...

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать чтобы решить данную задачу? Что у вас именно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, старший или младший байт... Потому написал для обоих.

```
int main()
{
    assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(unsigned int));
    float f,save;
    scanf("%f",&f);
    save = f;
    unsigned int * p = (unsigned int *)&f;
    printf("%10f   %08X\n",f,*p);
    *p = (*p&0xFFFFFF00) | 0xAA;   // Младший байт
    printf("%10f   %08X\n",f,*p);
    f = save;
    *p = (*p&0x00FFFFFF) | (0xAA << 24);  // Старший байт
    printf("%10f   %08X\n",f,*p);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий подход

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

//...

float x = 123.456789;

std::cout << "x = " << std::setprecision(16) << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>( x ) << std::endl;

reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>(x) &= ~(uint32_t)0 << 8;

std::cout << "x = " << std::setprecision( 16 ) << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>(x) << std::endl;

reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>(x) |= (uint32_t)0xAA;

std::cout << "x = " << std::setprecision(16) << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>(x) << std::endl;
```

Вывод данного фрагмента кода может выглядеть как

```
x = 123.456787109375
x = 42f6e9e0
x = 123.455078125
x = 42f6e900
x = 123.4563751220703
x = 42f6e9aa
```

Или то же самое можно сделать, используя указатель. Например

```
float x = 123.456789;

uint32_t *px = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(&x);

std::cout << "x = " << std::setprecision(16) << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << *px << std::endl;

*px &= ~(uint32_t)0 << 8;

std::cout << "x = " << std::setprecision( 16 ) << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << *px << std::endl;

*px |= (uint32_t)0xAA;

std::cout << "x = " << std::setprecision(16) << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << *px << std::endl;
```

Вывод на консоль этого фрагмента кода будет таким же, как показано выше.